# Hibernate: Set one-to-many reference of a new database object to another object without acquiring the existing one first

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm building an application using Hibernate. I work with a database schema that contains (amongst others) two tables called `assignment` and `assignment_type`. The latter contains primary key / value pairs that describe the type of the `assignment` (e.g. "written", "practical").

`assignment`, however, is an abstract class extended by such classes as `written_assignment` and `practical_assignment`. For this I'm using the **class table inheritance** approach ([some details on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3579462/3625721)).

Now, it would make sense to set a reference to the appropriate object in the `assignment_type` during the creation of instances of classes like `written_assignment`, something like this:

```
public WrittenAssignment() {
    AssignmentType assignmentType = ...; // Create or acquire appropriate instance
    this.setAssignmentType(assignmentType);
}
```

As far as I understand it, going with the "create instance" approach will only work once, that one time being the state when there is no object in the database yet with that value (since the value of the `assignment_type` table is set to be unique).

Is there a way to set a reference to an object from `assignment_type` in the constructor of `WrittenAssignment` without acquiring it first? Bonus question: can it be created if no matching object exists yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the column that references the `assignment_type` table from the `assignment` table as a discriminator column, and then map the `AssignmentType` relation as a read only `@ManyToOne`, setting `insertable` and `updatable` to `false`.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="ASSIGNMENT_TYPE_ID")
@Table(name="assignment")
public abstract class Assignment {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ASSIGNMENT_TYPE_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private AssignmentType assignmentType;
}
```

In the child class, put the appropiate discriminator column value with the `@DiscriminatorValue` annotation:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("W")
@Table(name="written_assignment")
public class WrittenAssignment extends Assignment {
    ...
}
```

When you need to create a new child entity, use the constructor and the assignment type would be implicit due to the child entity discriminator. When you read an existing entity instance and fetch the associated assignment type, the corresponding assignment type will be loaded.

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm!

Any chance the discriminator can be used to automatically fetch the appropriate child class when dealing with a query on the superclass?

Comment: Try to execute a query of `Assignment` entities, the returned real class of the result instances must be of the concrete type (not the parent abstract type).

Comment: Thanks again! That would be the behaviour I'd expect, and it works partially. I tweaked the `toString` methods so that they identify the real class, which works. However, I can't check for the child class by using `instanceof`, nor can I typecast it. `getClass().getName()` returns the name of the abstract class, followed by a bunch of underscores, dollar signs and other characters. I suppose this may be something about reflections that I don't understand.

Comment: The `instanceof` operator must be working. Another way you can try to check the real class is to make a debug session in your IDE and inspect the results: it must show you the real class of the result instances.

Comment: The debugger indeed reveals the real classname that I expect, but with a trailing `@` followed by a number. `instanceof` doesn't work, I'm checking it like this: `for (Assignment a : user.getAssignments()) System.out.println(a instanceof WrittenAssignment);` -- which always prints `false` (`user` being an instance of another mapping class containing a `Set` of `Assignment`s).

Comment: If you are lazy fetching the `Set` of `Assignment` of the user object, Hibernate may create `Assignment` proxies for every entity on the `Set`, and the `instanceof` operator won't work with that proxies. But if you directly make a HQL query like `"SELECT a FROM Assignment a WHERE a.user = :user"` using the desired `user` object as a query parameter, the returned list elements will be real instances of the child classes (`WrittenAssignment`, etc).